# mongo: must be an instance of int not long

Tags: python, mongodb

I run the code in python 2.7 and windows 7. with mongo v4.2.3

```
from nut.mongo import connection
_c = connection['pandora'].contacts
_contact = _c.Contacts()
_contact['_id'] = 'duwenbin'
_contact['contact_address_data_id'] = int('170511111552051000')
_contact.save()
```

and show exception:

`SchemaTypeError: contact_address_data_id must be an instance of int not long`

but I run the same code in ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with python 2.7 , with mongo v3.2.9

the code run normally!

Can somebody tell me why? I think the difference is the mongo version.
But I am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running windows x64 or windows x86?

Comment: windows x64 system

Answer (score 0):

32-bit systems and 64-bit systems have different `int` sizes.  To verify where `int` stops and `long` begins you can check the `sys.maxint` value on both your ubuntu server and your windows local machine.  For example, on my 64-bit machine, `sys.maxint` is `9223372036854775807` (which is 2^63 - 1 since `sys.maxint` is the maximum *signed* `int`).  Of course, you can also switch to python3 where there is no longer an `int` and just a `long`.

Comment: Thank you, But the 64-bit windows show `sys.maxint` value: 2147483647